# C++ Variables not changing

Tags: c++, variables, sdl, frame-rate, zero

I have a `Timer` class, but whenever I attempt to change a value of any variable, the variable just remains at zero. `SDL_GetTicks()` returns the value it is supposed to, but when I attempt to assign that value to a variable, that variable remains at zero. I have tried hardcoding in numbers, and the variable still remains at zero. The variables in my `Main` class work just fine, but when I attempt to change any of the ones in this, it doesn't work. Also, the method `timeSinceCreation()` returns zero as well.

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include "SDL.h"

Timer::Timer() : m_timeOfLastCall(0.0f)
{
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER);
}

Timer::~Timer() {}

float Timer::timeSinceCreation()
{
 return SDL_GetTicks();
 }

float Timer::timeSinceLastFrame()
{
 float thisTime = timeSinceCreation();
 float deltaTime = thisTime - m_timeOfLastCall;
m_timeOfLastCall = thisTime;
printf("%u ms \n", thisTime );
return deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Might be your output that's wrong? Try: `printf("%.8e ms\n");`, or look at the documentation for `stdio` format strings.

Comment: Your statement seems confusing to me. You say `SDL_GetTicks()` returns correct value and `timeSinceCreation()` returns zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behaviour because your `printf` call has have a mismatched type (`%u` requires an `unsigned int`, but you are passing in a `float`). As a result, you should not expect any reasonable behaviour.

Comment: Aha! Thank you, I changed it to %f and it works great now! Thanks!

Comment: @user2117614: Actually, if I were you, I'd change types of all the variables to [Uint32](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL-1.3-docs/SDL__stdinc_8h.html#d020192d056a8515c4c779266da4064a), which is the type of the values returned by [SDL_GetTicks](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlgetticks.html).